# git pull heroku master failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I am trying to pull the latest code pushed from another developer to the heroku deployed to my local system:

I executed following:

```
$ git pull heroku master failed
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
remote: Counting objects: 13, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
remote: Total 8 (delta 5), reused 1 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (8/8), done.
From https://git.heroku.com/titan-demo
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      master     -> heroku/master
Auto-merging db/schema.rb
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in db/schema.rb
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Comment: [_fix conflicts and then commit the result_](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line/).

Comment: this might be because you are using pg in heroku and different database in your local. BTW why do you want to pull heroku master ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Comment: [_Please_ don't use Heroku as your primary code sharing mechanism.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app): "Heroku provides the git service primarily for deployment, and the ability to clone from it is offered as a convenience. We strongly recommend you store your code in another git repository such as [GitHub](https://github.com/) and treat that as canonical."

Comment: You can get that code DIRECTLY from that other developer.  One of the remarkable features of git is that it does not require a centralized server.  In the days before the Internet code was shared directly from machine to machine.  All you need is access to that other developer's machine by SSH, HTTP; in both cases he runs a server on his machine.

Answer (score -1):

```
CONFLICT occurs in following file at that time the git could not auto merge the CONFLICT so you will remove the conflict in manually in this file db/schema.rb. the file conflict location is denoted as below syntax so you will remove unnecessary code and after you push the code. 

// CONFLICT Example
<<<<<<<<<<<< HEAD *code from develop*
>>>>>>>>>>develop *code form your's*
```